# Python module ortools apparently installs incompletely

Tags: python, or-tools

I am trying to set up `ortools` on my Mac.

I installed via `pip install ortools`.  I can verify that the package installed successfully.

```
 conda list | grep ortools
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
ortools                   7.1.6720                 pypi_0    pypi
```

When I try to use the library, it looks like there are missing functions.  I followed along with the example here:

https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/python

This returns an error:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple_ortools_example.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
ImportError: No module named ortools.linear_solver
```

I can import the module otherwise and look at the functions interactively:

```
>>> ortools.__
ortools.__cached__          ortools.__gt__(             ortools.__path__
ortools.__class__(          ortools.__hash__(           ortools.__reduce__(
ortools.__delattr__(        ortools.__init__(           ortools.__reduce_ex__(
ortools.__dict__            ortools.__init_subclass__(  ortools.__repr__(
ortools.__dir__(            ortools.__le__(             ortools.__setattr__(
ortools.__doc__             ortools.__loader__          ortools.__sizeof__(
ortools.__eq__(             ortools.__lt__(             ortools.__spec__
ortools.__file__            ortools.__name__            ortools.__str__(
ortools.__format__(         ortools.__ne__(             ortools.__subclasshook__(
ortools.__ge__(             ortools.__new__(            ortools.__version__
ortools.__getattribute__(   ortools.__package__
```

I just used tab complete here to see what was available.  Sure enough there is no linear_solver attached to the ortools module.

I'm a bit at a loss as to what to try next.  Any advice would be apreciated.

Comment: You can do `dir(ortools)` to find every attribute/method associated with the object `ortools`, after importing it. Try that and see if you find `linear_solver` anywhere in the list. Also, are you using python2 or python3, because your use of the `__future__` module implies that that might be an issue

Comment: It's a good point.  I am using python 3.6 and I know that a lot of Google is still on 2.7.

Comment: I tried 3.6 and 2.7, no linear_solver function attached to ortools in either case.

Comment: >>> dir(ortools)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downgraded to an earlier version which solves the problem.

`pip install ortools==6.7.4973`

Comment: ortools version 6.7.4973 is unavailable now, error message is :  `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ortools==6.7.4973 (from versions: 6.8.5452, 6.9.5822, 6.9.5824, 6.10.6025, 7.0b6150, 7.0.6546, 7.1.6720, 7.2.6977, 7.3.7083, 7.4.7247, 7.5.7466, 7.6.7691, 7.7.7810, 7.8.7959, 8.0.8283, 8.1.8487, 8.2.8710, 9.0.9048)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ortools==6.7.4973`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue today on Windows. Figured out that it is usually caused due to missing Microsoft Visual Studio 20** redistributables c++ ([see here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/737)).

This is how I solved it (Python 3.7.6, ortools Version: 7.5.*).

1. Got the latest Microsoft Visual Studio 20** redistributables c++ from https://support.microsoft.com/en-my/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c
   downloads
2. Installed it and Restarted the computer.
3. Uninstall the ortools 'python -m pip uninstall ortools'
4. Install back the ortools 'python -m pip install --user ortools'
5. Validated installation with python -c "from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp"